# .htaccess redirect request to a subfolder and get it masked

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have this:

```
www.website.com/subfolder1/
```

the actual website (main website) is under `/subfolder1/`

I want to put a .htaccess file to the root so when somebody goes to:

```
www.website.com/subfolder2/
```

the sites does not get forwarded to `/subfolder1/` but it shows the content from the `/subfolder1/` and looks like the visitor is under `/subfolder2/`
and when links are clicked shows e.g.: `www.website.com/subfolder1/link.php`

(the file 'link.php' actually lies under /subfolder1/

... so I don't have to recreate the main website all the time when a subfolder is created.

Comment: Not really clear what you want. Can you show your current .htacccess?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the easiest way would just be to forward *any* folder from root to /subfolder1/

```
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/(.*) /subfolder1/$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: it doesnt work - Ive created a.htacess file with this:  RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/(.*) /subfolder1/$1 [NC,L]

Comment: There are two possibilities: either you used the $1 (which would give a 404, likely) or change the /subfolder/ to subfolder/

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder1/
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ /subfolder1/$2 [L]
```

The above will silently redirect anything that isn't in the `subfolder1` to it. 
E.g. `http://example.com/subfolder2/about.php` will show the content from the `about.php` page in the `subfolder2`, but still showing `http://example.com/subfolder2/about.php` in the url.